# iPhone Mail, Send only account

Tags: iphone, email

I have an account on dreamhost that autoforwards everything on to my GMail. This is fine as it all gets pulled into my phone, but if I try to reply on my iPhone, it shows the google address, not the fancy forwarded address.

To fix this I attempted to add the forwarded account via IMAP to my phone, fixing the problem, and introducing a second. Now I have duplicates of emails one for GMail and one for the original account. What'smore, spam sent to the fancy email is not being filtered, so I'm getting both duplicates of normal emails, and unfiltered spam.

**What I'd like is to set my iPhone so it can send from that account, but either does not check for emails, or cannot check for emails.**

In the past I've set my phone up to use the 'from' trick, which has almost worked ( users can still tell it's not quite from that address though it gives the illusion ), and the instructions fail when applied to iOS5 ( impending death of the trick? )

Comment: A good answer at http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/145565/how-to-set-the-iphone-mail-app-to-send-email-only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the solution!

I set up a second email account on my server with an obscure name, then, I changed the POP/IMAP settings to use that account for receiving, and left the send/SMTP details unchanged.

This now gives me the desired behaviour. It also gives me a receive only account ( which could also be desirable ).

If you are on iOS4 or below, you can also refer to Hand-E-Food's answer. My instructions will work for iOS5 ( due to the extra checks iOS5 makes to verify what you've entered )

Answer (score 2):

Got it to work!

Step 1)  Create a new account on the same domain that will not receive emails.  (I would assume this might work using another domain IMAP address you have proper credentials for, however, this is not what I did or tested)

Step 2)  Create a new IMAP email account on iOS.  Provide only the credentials of the email account you want to use for sending emails (not the account created in Step 1).  Let it verify and completely setup this way.

Step 3)  Alter the new IMAP email account on iOS.  Change the Incoming Mail Server's User Name and Password to the account you created in Step 1.  Let it verify.

Step 4)  Alter your default account to this new account for sending emails in iOS.

Comment: This does work, but I'd already figured this out and posted the solution, sorry

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar set up.  I use mBox Mail to handle Hotmail.  I wanted a send-only account so I can use the iPhone integrated e-mail features (eg. e-mail this photo.)

1. Find the correct e-mail settings from your e-mail provider.
2. Open Settings, Mail Contacts Calendars, Add Account..., Other, Add Mail Account.
3. Set the following settings.

   Name: Your Name
   Address: your.address@provider.com
   Password: YourPassword
   Description: E-mail Provider (send only)
4. Press Next.
5. Set the following settings:

   IMAP/POP: as required

   **Account Information**
   Name: Your Name
   Address: your.address@provider.com
   Description: E-mail Provider (send only)

   **Incoming Mail Server**
   Host Name: mail.provider.com
   User Name: YourUserName
   Password: YourPassword

   **Outgoing Mail Server**
   Host Name: mail.provider.com
   User Name: YourUserName
   Password: YourPassword
6. Press Save.
7. Now press the account you've just created and remove some information.

   **Incoming Mail Server**
   Host Name: (blank)
   User Name: YourUserName
   Password: (blank)
8. Press Save.
9. Ignore any errors you receive.

Comment: These instructions are useless in iOS5. When removing those fields in the Incoming Mail server, the 'done' button is inactive, preventing progress.

Comment: Bugger...  What if you type a fake incoming server or an incorrect password?  It will try and fail, but not download your mail.

Comment: I thought of that and put example.com in the domain and pressed done, unfortunately the next step of the process is iOS5 verifying your settings by contacting the server and attempting a successful login. =(

Comment: Okay, getting convoluted now...  :-)  Change your email account's password to something simple, connect with your iPhone, then revert to your original password.

Comment: This would give me an email account that could not retrieve email yes, but it would also prevent me sending emails from that account also ( I only have 1 password field for both SMTP and IMAP on the server )

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (with Fastmail forwarding to Gmail) and solved it a different way. Rather than using the built-in default "Gmail" account type on my iPhone, I set my Gmail account up using the generic "Other" account type, which allows you to specify IMAP and SMTP server details separately. For the SMTP server details, I used my Fastmail credentials, and for the IMAP server details, I entered my Gmail credentials.